# Valgrind memory check when duplicating strings

Tags: c, string, memory-leaks, valgrind, heap-memory

I'm writing a program that implements a map\dictionary (those of you who are familiar with python should know it). Everything compiles and my tests are working correctly. The only issue I have is when I run the program with valgrind memory check.

The function which valgrind leads me into is the one who insert's an element into the dictionary (all elements are represented by struct that has 2 fields: char* key, char* value).

The code:

```
MapResult mapPut(Map map, const char* key, const char* data){
if( map == NULL || key == NULL || data == NULL){
    return MAP_NULL_ARGUMENT;
}

//check if key exists in map
if(mapContains(map, key)){//checks if the key already exists in the map
    if(strcmp(map->dictionary[elementIndex(map,key)].value, data) == 0){
        return MAP_SUCCESS;
    }

    else{
        char* new_value = copyString(data);
        if(new_value == NULL){
            return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
        }

        map->dictionary[elementIndex(map,key)].value = new_value;
        return MAP_SUCCESS;
    }
}
// expands the array if necessary
if(map->size == map->max_size){
    if(expand(map) == MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY){
        return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }
}
char* new_key = copyString(key);
char* new_value = copyString(data); //This is line 194
if(new_value == NULL || new_key == NULL){
    return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
}
map->dictionary[map->size].key = new_key;
map->dictionary[map->size++].value = new_value;

return MAP_SUCCESS;
}
```

The copyString function:

```
static char* copyString(const char* str){
char* new_str = malloc(strlen(str) + 1); //this is line 49
if(new_str == NULL){
    return NULL;
}
return strcpy(new_str, str);//returning the new string after it has been assigend with new value
```

}

The struct implemenation:

```
typedef struct element{
char* key;
char* value;
}*Element;
```

Apparently the leak is coming from copyString, I didn't manage to find what it is but I assume it somehow related to the string duplication process.

Valgrind output (all other blocks are the same, everything is categorized as definitely lost bytes) :

```
==4694== 7 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 3 of 5
==4694==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==4694==    by 0x108AB2: copyString (map.c:49)
==4694==    by 0x108FF3: mapPut (map.c:194)
==4694==    by 0x109A46: testMapPutGet (test_file.c:71)
==4694==    by 0x10B146: main (test_file.c:296)
```

if anyone finds the leak I'll be glad to hear

*edit*

The destroy function for the map:

```
void mapDestroy(Map map){
if(map == NULL){
    return;
}

while(mapGetSize(map) > 0){
    mapRemove(map, mapGetFirst(map));//map getFirst returns first key in the map\array
}
// TODO: Free key and value
free(map->dictionary);
free(map);
}


MapResult mapRemove(Map map, const char* key){
assert(map != NULL);
if(key == NULL){
    return MAP_NULL_ARGUMENT;
}

int index = elementIndex(map, key);
if(index == NOT_FOUND){
    return MAP_ITEM_DOES_NOT_EXIST;
}

return removeElement(map, index);
}

static MapResult removeElement(Map map, int index){
assert(map != NULL && map->size > 0);
free(map->dictionary[index].key);
free(map->dictionary[index].value);
for(int i = index; i < map->size - 1 ; i++){
    map->dictionary[i] = map->dictionary[i + 1];
}

if(map->size > 1){
    Element tmp = realloc(map->dictionary, (map->max_size - 1) * sizeof(*tmp));
    if(tmp == NULL){
        return MAP_OUT_OF_MEMORY;
    }

    map->max_size--;
    map->size--;
    map->dictionary = tmp;
    return MAP_SUCCESS;
}
else{
    map->size--;
    return MAP_SUCCESS;
}
}
```

Comment: What happens in `expand`, and what happens when the `map` holding this thing is eventually supposed to be destroyed? How is that done? Leaks happen when allocated memory is orphaned into the abyss. Valgrind can't tell you where it should be free'd; it can only tell you where it was allocated. Thus, the reference to the duplicator. Only *you* know where/when/if it should be free'd.

Comment: When the map needs to be destroyes there's a specific function for that, I'm attaching the code for that above right now.

Comment: Also expand actually expands the array for more elements to be entered.

Comment: `map->dictionary[elementIndex(map,key)].value = new_value;` pretty sure that's the leak. this happens when an key was found, but the data elements don't match. You never free the existing data value (pointer); just overwrite it.

Comment: Yes!!!! It's solved!!!! Thank you!!!!